# Choosing interests

Tags: career-path

I am a final yr physics bachelor student. In my first semester I was really interested in mechanics I used to solve and analyse examples and enjoy learning them but as time went by . It changed to mathematical physics where I enjoyed the concepts of divergence ,curl and line and surface integrals. And then I read modern physics and then the list goes on and on. I am not able to broadly come up with one particular branch in which I am deeply interested in. And the question ' what is the branch of your interest ' intimidates me . I want to know is it necessary at this stage for ke to figure out the answer to this question. Or can I take one more year and wait for my master's to approach and decide what specialisation to take in my second yr of master's ? Please help me . All the advices would be of a great help to me . Currently i am studying special relativity classical mechanics and solid state physics.

Comment: You should talk to your advisor / mentor...

Comment: If you don't have any research experience in any particular subfield, I doubt your stated interest would carry too much weight -- being undecided is probably fine for now. More generally, I recommend focusing on fields that will give you transferrable skills -- e.g., computers, signal processing, statistics, etc.

Comment: Completely unrelated to your question, but worth pointing out nonetheless: You would do well to get in the habit of proof reading anything you put out for general consumption.

Answer (score 1):

talk to graduating undergrads or masters. Ask about their job prospects, and which branch they chose. List branches with decent job prospects, and pick one or two that you like best (or hate the least, and have good grades in).